# awk to store value of specific row and column of csv in variable

Tags: awk

I am trying to store the Date value in the 3rd row, second column (always this position) in `var` using `awk`. The code executes and `echo`  the current result, not the desired. If I understand the code the value in the 3rd row, second column is printed and stored in `var`. Thank you :).

**file**

```
[ID]
Sample,one,,,
Date,1/1/2015,,,
Test,xxx,,,

[Data]
....,,,
....,,,
```

**desired**

```
echo var 
1/1/2015
```

**current**

```
echo var
one 1/1/2015 xxx
```

**awk**

```
var=$(awk -F, -v r=3 -v c=2 '{print $c}' file)
```

Comment: `NR==r{print $c}`??

Comment: The INI file format creates extra complications. Do you want the row/column value for each section, or only the ID section?

Comment: Only the `ID` section as this will always contain the Date. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this program will get the output you need:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}/Date/ {print $2}' file
```

or:

```
awk -F, '/Date/ {print $2}' file
```

(option 01) the solution you need is:

```
var=$(awk -F, '/Date/ {print $2}' file)
echo "$var"
```

based in solution you proposed, you can print only the **third row**:

```
awk -F, -v r=3 -v c=2 '{if(NR==r)print $c}' file
```

(option 02)

```
var=$(awk -F, -v r=3 -v c=2 '{if(NR==r)print $c}' file)
echo "$var"
```

Comment: `{if(NR==r)print $c}` is more awkishly written `NR==r{print $c}` and always quote your shell variables - `echo "$var"`, not `echo $var` (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, good explanation/manual. I've included ```echo "$var"``` in the solution by your suggestion.